How Can I Seal a Sensor into a Cylindrical Tank?
I am trying to seal a dissolved CO2 sensor (From Oxyguard) and a dissolved O2 sensor into a cylindrical tank with a PVC cap. I have a few constraints. The tank will need to be pressurized so I need to create a seal that will prevent gas from escaping. I am willing to attach the sensors from the side or the cap. I am expecting the pressure inside the tank to be less than 60 psi. Second, I need the threading to be 3/4 inch to 1 inch if the seal involves a thread. Third, as the pressure is max 60 psi, anything that we stick into the tank may pop off (we cannot glue the sensors into the tank, they need to be removable) Additionally, there are two sensors that will need to be attached to the tank (as mentioned before). I have attached pictures of them below so you can get an idea of the shape and size. I have also attached pictures of the tank/cap so you guys can get an idea of the shape of the tank as well. Please let me know if any solutions come to mind.





60 psi is pretty tame. Compression (or flare) fittings and tubes potted with epoxy and/or rtv are typical fare

You can use solvent cement to attach mounting bosses anywhere on the interior. Getting the signal out will be the hard part. If you can tolerate minor leakage, you may be able to pass the cable through a water tight cord grip. If the seal needs to be very good, you may need to pass it through in an array of solid metal pins. These will be much easier to form perfect (ish) seal around.
